# Ruby attr_accessor :name to :name[] array

Tags: ruby, arrays, attr-accessor

How would I create an attr_accessor to array?

for example

```
class MyClass

  attr_accessor :my_attr_accessor

  def initialize()
  end

  def add_new_value(new_array)
    @my_attr_accessor += new_array
    return @my_attr_accessor
  end

end

my_class = MyClass.new
my_class.my_attr_accessor = 1
my_class.my_attr_accessor[1] = 2
my_class.my_attr_accessor.push = 3
my_class.add_new_value(5)

my_class.my_attr_accessor
=> [1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an instance variable that points to an array and make an accessor from that instance variable.

Inside your class include something like this:

```
attr_accessor :my_attr_accessor
def initialize
    @my_attr_accessor = []
end
```

Note that using`attr_accessor` will allow you to change the value of the variable. If you want to ensure that the array stays, use `attr_reader` in place of `attr_accessor`. You will still be able to access and set array elements and perform operations on the array but you won't be able to replace it with a new value and using `+=` for concatenation will not work.

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for 1:Fixnum
NoMethodError: undefined method `push=' for 1:Fixnum

Comment: This is because of `my_class.my_attr_accessor = 1`. To help guard against this sort of thing, you could use `attr_reader` instead of `attr_accessor`. Also use `.push 3` not `.push = 3`

Comment: @rubies This is because your code `my_class.my_attr_accessor = 1` replaces the array value with the value of `1`. You probably want `my_class.my_attr_accessor << 1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with the Array always existing, @david4dev's answer is good. If you only want the array to pop into existence on the first usage, and never want the user to be able to replace it with a new array (via assignment):

```
class MyClass
  def my_attr_accessor
    @my_attr_accessor ||= []
  end
  def add_new_value( value )
    my_attr_accessor << value
  end
  def add_new_values( values_array )
    my_attr_accessor.concat values_array
  end
end
```

*The user could still call `my_class.my_attr_accessor.replace( [] )` to wipe it out.*